# ThinkingSphinx indexing where condition is in joined table

Tags: thinking-sphinx

How to make index only records of active users, in my scenario i need to index messages but only of users who are active

so in messages model

```
define_index do
indexes messages.subject
indexes messages body

where "messages.user.is_active = 1"
end
```

How can this conditional clause be implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a field for the association. After indexing the data the generated SQL query in `config/development.sphinx.conf`, will then have the join.

```
define index do
  indexes subject
  indexes body
  indexes user.is_active, :as => :user_is_active

  where "user.is_active = 1"
end
```